# Enable top processes log in oom-killer log

Tags: ubuntu, logging, debian, out-of-memory, syslog

We have a system running debian squeeze which is running out of memory from time to time.
We are catching the event when oom-killer gets invoked and logs its activity.

When looking at the log, debian is logging the event **without listing the processes** at the time like ubuntu does for example.

This is an example of the oom-log we are getting:

```
    Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: java invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x200da, order=0, oom_adj=0
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: [<c002dd94>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf0) from [<c02f86c0>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: [<c02f86c0>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c) from [<c008a27c>] (dump_header+0x70/0x170)
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: [<c008a27c>] (dump_header+0x70/0x170) from [<c008a3c0>] (oom_kill_process+0x44/0xdc)
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: [<c008a3c0>] (oom_kill_process+0x44/0xdc) from [<c008aaac>] (__out_of_memory+0x194/0x1b8)
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: [<c008aaac>] (__out_of_memory+0x194/0x1b8) from [<c008ab80>] (out_of_memory+0xb0/0x104)
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: [<c008ab80>] (out_of_memory+0xb0/0x104) from [<c008db74>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x420/0x514)
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: [<c008db74>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x420/0x514) from [<c009da40>] (handle_mm_fault+0x1b8/0x744)
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: [<c009da40>] (handle_mm_fault+0x1b8/0x744) from [<c02fd430>] (do_page_fault+0x17c/0x334)
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: [<c02fd430>] (do_page_fault+0x17c/0x334) from [<c00272e0>] (do_DataAbort+0x3c/0x9c)
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: [<c00272e0>] (do_DataAbort+0x3c/0x9c) from [<c02fb844>] (ret_from_exception+0x0/0x10)
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: Exception stack(0xc7671fb0 to 0xc7671ff8)
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: 1fa0:                                     5bafbfe8 43e4f420 00006670 00000000
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: 1fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 000015d0
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: 1fe0: 00000000 86df5370 403d37cc 404f3114 20000010 ffffffff
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: Mem-info:
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: Normal per-cpu:
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: CPU    0: hi:   42, btch:   7 usd:   6
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: active_anon:22174 inactive_anon:6879 isolated_anon:0
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: active_file:3 inactive_file:24 isolated_file:0
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: free:360 slab_reclaimable:280 slab_unreclaimable:552
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: mapped:18 shmem:9 pagetables:161 bounce:0
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: Normal free:1440kB min:1440kB low:1800kB high:2160kB active_anon:88696kB inactive_anon:27516kB active_file:12kB     inactive_file:96kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:130048kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:72kB shmem:36kB     slab_reclaimable:1120kB slab_unreclaimable:2208kB kernel_stack:528kB pagetables:644kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:27     all_unreclaimable? no
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: Normal: 36*4kB 16*8kB 9*16kB 4*32kB 4*64kB 3*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 1440kB
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: 36 total pagecache pages
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: 0 pages in swap cache
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: Total swap = 0kB
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: 32768 pages of RAM
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: 500 free pages
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: 1372 reserved pages
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: 549 slab pages
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: 164 pages shared
Jun  1 17:33:52 SDcard kernel: 0 pages swap cached
```

> **We want to enable a processes list dump** like shown at the end of the oom-log below:

```
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529514] irqbalance invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x80d0, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529516] irqbalance cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529518] Pid: 948, comm: irqbalance Not tainted 3.2.0-55-generic-pae #85-Ubuntu
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529519] Call Trace:
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529525]  [] dump_header.isra.6+0x85/0xc0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529528]  [] oom_kill_process+0x5c/0x80
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529530]  [] out_of_memory+0xc5/0x1c0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529532]  [] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x72c/0x740
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529535]  [] __get_free_pages+0x1c/0x30
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529537]  [] get_zeroed_page+0x12/0x20
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529541]  [] fill_read_buffer.isra.8+0xaa/0xd0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529543]  [] sysfs_read_file+0x7d/0x90
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529546]  [] vfs_read+0x8c/0x160
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529548]  [] ? fill_read_buffer.isra.8+0xd0/0xd0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529550]  [] sys_read+0x3d/0x70
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529554]  [] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529555] Mem-Info:
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529556] DMA per-cpu:
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529557] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529558] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529560] CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529561] CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529562] CPU    4: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529563] CPU    5: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529564] CPU    6: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529565] CPU    7: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529566] Normal per-cpu:
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529567] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 179
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529568] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 182
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529569] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 132
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529570] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 175
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529571] CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  91
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529572] CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 173
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529573] CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 159
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529574] CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 164
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529575] HighMem per-cpu:
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529576] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 165
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529577] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 183
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529578] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 185
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529579] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 138
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529580] CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 155
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529581] CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 104
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529582] CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 133
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529583] CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 170
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529586] active_anon:5523 inactive_anon:354 isolated_anon:0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529586]  active_file:2815 inactive_file:6849119 isolated_file:0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529587]  unevictable:0 dirty:449 writeback:10 unstable:0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529587]  free:1304125 slab_reclaimable:104672 slab_unreclaimable:3419
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529588]  mapped:2661 shmem:138 pagetables:313 bounce:0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529591] DMA free:4252kB min:780kB low:972kB high:1168kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:4kB     inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15756kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB     slab_reclaimable:11564kB slab_unreclaimable:4kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:1     all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529594] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 869 32460 32460
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529599] Normal free:44052kB min:44216kB low:55268kB high:66324kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB     active_file:616kB inactive_file:568kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:890008kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB     mapped:4kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:407124kB slab_unreclaimable:13672kB kernel_stack:992kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB     pages_scanned:2083 all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529602] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 252733 252733
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529606] HighMem free:5168196kB min:512kB low:402312kB high:804112kB active_anon:22092kB     inactive_anon:1416kB active_file:10640kB inactive_file:27395920kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:32349872kB     mlocked:0kB dirty:1796kB writeback:40kB mapped:10640kB shmem:552kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:1252kB     unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529609] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529611] DMA: 6*4kB 6*8kB 6*16kB 5*32kB 5*64kB 4*128kB 2*256kB 1*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 4232kB
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529616] Normal: 297*4kB 180*8kB 119*16kB 73*32kB 67*64kB 47*128kB 35*256kB 13*512kB 5*1024kB 1*2048kB     1*4096kB = 44052kB
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529622] HighMem: 1*4kB 6*8kB 27*16kB 11*32kB 2*64kB 1*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 4*1024kB 1*2048kB 1260*4096kB     = 5168196kB
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529627] 6852076 total pagecache pages
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529628] 0 pages in swap cache
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529629] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529630] Free swap  = 3998716kB
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.529631] Total swap = 3998716kB
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571914] 8437743 pages RAM
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571916] 8209409 pages HighMem
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571917] 159556 pages reserved
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571917] 6862034 pages shared
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571918] 123540 pages non-shared
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571919] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss cpu oom_adj oom_score_adj name
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571927] [  421]     0   421      709      152   3       0             0 upstart-udev-br
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571929] [  429]     0   429      773      326   5     -17         -1000 udevd
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571931] [  567]     0   567      772      224   4     -17         -1000 udevd
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571932] [  568]     0   568      772      231   7     -17         -1000 udevd
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571934] [  764]     0   764      712      103   1       0             0 upstart-socket-
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571936] [  772]   103   772      815      164   5       0             0 dbus-daemon
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571938] [  785]     0   785     1671      600   1     -17         -1000 sshd
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571940] [  809]   101   809     7766      380   1       0             0 rsyslogd
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571942] [  869]     0   869     1158      213   3       0             0 getty
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571943] [  873]     0   873     1158      214   6       0             0 getty
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571945] [  911]     0   911     1158      215   3       0             0 getty
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571947] [  912]     0   912     1158      214   2       0             0 getty
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571949] [  914]     0   914     1158      213   1       0             0 getty
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571950] [  916]     0   916      618       86   1       0             0 atd
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571952] [  917]     0   917      655      226   3       0             0 cron
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571954] [  948]     0   948      902      159   3       0             0 irqbalance
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571956] [  993]     0   993     1145      363   3       0             0 master
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571957] [ 1002]   104  1002     1162      333   1       0             0 qmgr
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571959] [ 1016]     0  1016      730      149   2       0             0 mdadm
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571961] [ 1057]     0  1057     6066     2160   3       0             0 /usr/sbin/apach
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571963] [ 1086]     0  1086     1158      213   3       0             0 getty
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571965] [ 1088]    33  1088     6191     1517   0       0             0 /usr/sbin/apach
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571967] [ 1089]    33  1089     6191     1451   1       0             0 /usr/sbin/apach
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571969] [ 1090]    33  1090     6175     1451   3       0             0 /usr/sbin/apach
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571971] [ 1091]    33  1091     6191     1451   1       0             0 /usr/sbin/apach
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571972] [ 1092]    33  1092     6191     1451   0       0             0 /usr/sbin/apach
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571974] [ 1109]    33  1109     6191     1517   0       0             0 /usr/sbin/apach
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571976] [ 1151]    33  1151     6191     1451   1       0             0 /usr/sbin/apach
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571978] [ 1201]   104  1201     1803      652   1       0             0 tlsmgr
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571980] [ 2475]     0  2475     2435      812   0       0             0 sshd
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571982] [ 2494]     0  2494     1745      839   1       0             0 bash
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571984] [ 2573]     0  2573     3394     1689   0       0             0 sshd
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571986] [ 2589]     0  2589     5014      457   3       0             0 rsync
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571988] [ 2590]     0  2590     7970      522   1       0             0 rsync
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571990] [ 2652]   104  2652     1150      326   5       0             0 pickup
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.571992] Out of memory: Kill process 421 (upstart-udev-br) score 1 or sacrifice child
Oct 25 07:28:04 nldedip4k031 kernel: [87946.572407] Killed process 421 (upstart-udev-br) total-vm:2836kB, anon-rss:156kB, file-rss:452kB
```